# Reactstrap generic flex directives

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm using Reactstrap to style my React/Redux app, and I'm having some trouble aligning things as I'd like; I know I'm giving up easy access to finer-grained control using the library, but I suspect there's a way to do what I want.

So, I have a basic Navbar at the top of my content (I compressed the Nav options).

```
<Navbar light expand={ "lg" }>
    <NavbarBrand>Redacted Name</NavbarBrand>
    <NavbarToggler onClick={ () => this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen }) } />
    <Collapse navbar isOpen={ this.state.isOpen }>
        <Nav navbar>
            <UncontrolledDropdown className={ "mr-lg-2" } nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav>
                    About Us
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownItem>
                        <Link to={ "/" }>Mission Statement</Link>
                    </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
        </Nav>
        { userOptions }
    </Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Now, `userOptions` is a form that changes based on user input, but all... forms of it take this basic inline form layout, save for differences in buttons and links inside.

```
<Form className={ "userStatusForm" } inline >
    // Content
</Form>
```

Here's my issue: in the simple layout I'm using, the brand, toggle, nav, and user form pile against each other on the left. However, I'm wanting content inside the Collapse element to use a standard "justify content between" alignment to press the user form against the right side, regardless of its size. That said, I'm struggling to find what I need in the Reactstrap docs - and to phrase what I'm trying to do correctly for Google.

Comment: How does your form fit into a navbar? A demo or screenshot would be great. It should probably be contained by something, or you should use more standard [layout](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/) directives and style it like a navbar.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/i8SzUnP

Comment: There's not a lot of space here, but when the user signs in, the greeting and links look stupid left-justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was trying to avoid direct `className` assignments, since I've already decided to use the Reactstrap library, but the simplest thing involved a `mr-auto` class added on to the `Nav` component that forms the first item inside the `Collapse` container. Not as elegant as I'd hoped, but it's simple (and was good enough for the `Navbar` in the Reactstrap docs).